# SQL group results by date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ms-access

I'm having trouble grouping the data I get by dates (specificaly by the day).

Would it be possible to do this within the sql or with the pdo fetchall()?

I know how to do this in PHP the "lame" way (loop through the data and process it how I need to to get the desired structure), but is there a smart way to go about this?

```
 $sql = "SELECT times.userid AS 'id', times.time AS 'time'
            FROM times
            WHERE ((times.userid) IN ($ids)) AND (times.time BETWEEN #$from# AND #$to#)
            ORDER BY times.time ASC;";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->execute();

    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
    return $data;
```

Result with the above code is:

```
[815] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2018-01-01 05:00:00
            [1] => 2018-01-02 08:00:00
            [2] => 2018-01-03 03:00:00
            [3] => 2018-01-03 06:00:00
            [4] => 2018-01-04 03:00:00
            [5] => 2018-01-04 04:00:00
            [6] => 2018-01-05 01:00:00
            [7] => 2018-01-05 03:00:00
            [8] => 2018-01-08 04:00:00
            [9] => 2018-01-09 05:00:00
        )
```

The result that I want to get is something like this:

```
[815] => Array
        (
            [2018-01-01] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 2018-01-01 05:00:00
                            )
            [2018-01-02] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 2018-01-02 08:00:00
                            )
            [2018-01-03] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 2018-01-03 03:00:00
                                [0] => 2018-01-03 06:00:00
                            )
            [2018-01-04] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 2018-01-04 03:00:00
                                [0] => 2018-01-04 04:00:00
                            )
            [2018-01-05 => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 2018-01-05 01:00:00
                                [0] => 2018-01-05 03:00:00
                            )
            [2018-01-08] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 2018-01-08 04:00:00
                            )
            [2018-01-09] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 2018-01-09 05:00:00
                            )
        )
```

Comment: Do it via application code

Comment: IIRC `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP` groups by the first column in your `SELECT`. What happens if you select `DATE_FORMAT(times.time, "%Y-%m-%d")` as the first column?

Comment: I think @rickdenhaan is onto something. As you still want to have the first aggregation level by `id`, I'd keep it as first column, then comes the expression given by @rickdenhaan, and last goes the `time`. I'm not sure how the sort order influences the PHP grouping, so either ditch it (for DB performance) or use the grouping order (for PHP performance). Also consider prepared statements / parameterized queries - yours is probably vulnerable to SQL injection.